# non-static variable record cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

Error is pointing to variable record : non-static variable record cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
public class RecordOption {
    // global variable
    String[][] record = new String[10][3];

    // addRecords method
    public static void addRecords(String studentRecords) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter Student Number:");
        String studNumber = br.readLine();
        record[0][0] = studNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the "Related" section at the right.

Comment: You need to understand what `static` vs `non-static` mean first. `static` means associated with the class. `non-static` means associated with an object. `record` in this case is `non-static` which means it can only be accessed from an object. The way you are trying to access it is in a static way. That's why the compiler is not happy.

Comment: how/ what changes should I need to do/

Answer (score 2):

The `record` variable must be static.

non-static variables can only be accessed from a non-static method, while static variables can be accessed from both non-static and static methods.

If you want to access non-static variable, you first need an instantiated object the variable is associated with. But if you want to access static variable, you just need the class.